# How to pass a value using Submit button that comes from an Ajax function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 written in C# and need to find a way to return a value (string in my case) that was optained from an Ajax callback when the user presses the Submit button.
Here are the deatils:

1. I have 2 editors in the form and a button acting as a Submit for the form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Tarjetas", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.DevExpress().TextBoxFor(m => m.CardId, tb =>
    {
      tb.ShowModelErrors = true;
      tb.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(150);
      tb.Properties.Caption = "Card Ident.";
      tb.Properties.CaptionSettings.Position = EditorCaptionPosition.Top;
      tb.Properties.ClientInstanceName = "editCardId";
      tb.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
      tb.Properties.ClientSideEvents.TextChanged = "OnTarjetaIdTextChanged";
      tb.Properties.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;
      tb.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.Text;
      tb.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorTextPosition = ErrorTextPosition.Bottom;
    }).GetHtml()
    @Html.DevExpress().TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, tb =>
    {
      tb.ShowModelErrors = true;
      tb.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(300);
      tb.Properties.Caption = "Email";
      tb.Properties.CaptionSettings.Position = EditorCaptionPosition.Top;
      tb.Properties.ClientInstanceName = "editEmail";
      tb.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
      tb.Properties.ValidationSettings.Display = Display.Dynamic;
      tb.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.Text;
      tb.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorTextPosition = ErrorTextPosition.Bottom;
    }).GetHtml()
    <br />
    @Html.DevExpress().Button(b =>
    {
      b.Name = "btnGuardar";
      b.Text = "Save";
      b.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
      b.RenderMode = ButtonRenderMode.Button;
      b.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Pixel(300);
    }).GetHtml()
}
```

2. When the user introduces text in the CardId field, an Ajax callback is called:

```js
function OnTarjetaIdTextChanged(sender, e)
{

  var tarjetaId = sender.GetText().toUpperCase();
  if(sender == editTarjetaBonaCompraId)
  {
    $.ajax(
      {
        url: "@Url.Action("ValidateBonaCompraTarjetaId", "Tarjetas")",
        type: 'post',
        data: { tarjetaId: tarjetaId },
      }).done(function(data)
      {
        //--- Structure de data = data.IsValid, data.Email
        btnGuardar.SetEnabled(data.IsValid);
        if(data.IsValid)
        {
          editEmail.SetValue(data.Email);
          editEmail.SetEnabled(!data.IsValid);
          sender.GetMainElement().title = validBonaCompraTitle;
          $(sender.GetMainElement()).css('background-color', '#FFF');
          $(sender.GetInputElement()).css('background-color', '#FFF');
        }
        else
        {
          sender.GetMainElement().title = "Not a valid card or already linked";
          $(sender.GetMainElement()).css('background-color', '#FFCCFF');
          $(sender.GetInputElement()).css('background-color', '#FFCCFF');
        }
      }).fail(function(data)
      {
        sender.GetMainElement().title = "Not a valid card";
        $(editNifCif.GetMainElement()).css('background-color', '#FFCCFF');
        $(editNifCif.GetInputElement()).css('background-color', '#FFCCFF');
      });
  }
}
```

3. Here is the problem, I want to save the data.Email value so I can pass it back to the controller when the form is submitted. I put the value in the editEmail editor - which is bound to the Model, but when the form is submitted, editEmail editor does not contain the data.Email value (which may be edited), it still contains the original Model value.

I know I can't update the Model from Javascript, so how can I send the updated value to the controller when it's submitted?

As you can see, I'm no expert in this area, so any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Martin.

Comment: What is the implementation of editEmail.SetValue(data.Email) ... how are you attempting to store/persist the value? It sounds like editEmail is reloading on postback and retrieving the Model value that hasn't been updated yet. A HiddenField in editEmail might be an option.

Comment: Catherine: Coming from a WinForms environment, I was hoping that using editEmail.SetValue(data.Email), as the editEmail field is bound to the Model, the value would update the Model so when it is submitted, I would get the value I set with editEmail.SetValue(data.Email) or the user edited value. I'm beginning to think this might not be the case.

Comment: are you interested to save value in session or cookie or in input hidden tag? @MartinHT

Comment: @MartinHT unfortunately I haven't dealt with the voodoo of bindings for a while so have no more to add. But it does seem that it might not be the case. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Alireza Madad: I have no preference where the value is stored, I just need the value to be sent to the Controller when the form is submitted.